# Randomize one column of matrices in list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, sample

I have a list `lst` that contains 3 matrices and I'd like to shuffle the values in, f.e., column `3`. How can I do that?

I have:

```
lapply(lst, \(x) sample(x[,3]))
```

but I don't know how to assign the sampled columns.

**EDIT**: `dput(lst)`:

```
list(structure(c(284.190191328526, 275.720694586635, 277.151402309537, 
251.027558222413, 260.092776268721, 261.799371317029, 259.013641774654, 
268.970000296831, 270.491042807698, 281.670583188534, 277.505417019129, 
278.831141069531, 265.090487375855, 259.860835596919, 259.975585192442, 
283.792229965329, 278.662678897381, 279.944456294179, 282.146671935916, 
279.153416529298, 280.239875465631, 270.852381959558, 270.976897478104, 
271.836298704147, 243.119602054358, 248.854640349746, 250.075380727649, 
283.831293657422, 277.869197651744, 279.148533567786, 0, 0, 0
), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "gt"))), structure(c(280.91616563499, 
283.042695373297, 277.835016921163, 264.65102083981, 255.473494678736, 
259.733878597617, 272.373424470425, 265.356608778238, 268.645283356309, 
282.002624571323, 282.229682281613, 279.619739353657, 261.796929836273, 
262.465895563364, 261.965392008424, 283.360087871552, 283.860591426492, 
281.140781864524, 283.106173872948, 283.616443350911, 281.421552151442, 
272.81289100647, 273.41837823391, 272.446668893099, 252.778099924326, 
245.238807350397, 249.279458001256, 282.945036143064, 283.142796084285, 
280.068971812725, 1, 0, 0), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gt"))), 
    structure(c(286.072572991252, 279.421979412436, 276.038087084889, 
    267.942136898637, 256.398815885186, 266.247749254107, 274.289986863732, 
    266.313669234514, 270.246894732118, 285.440229475498, 280.703756809235, 
    275.937986373901, 265.036774799228, 262.966399118304, 256.784569844604, 
    286.931974217296, 282.256538569927, 276.66066467762, 286.971037909389, 
    281.526535823941, 277.053743079305, 275.339823588729, 271.836298704147, 
    268.73805962503, 258.627887815237, 243.874019607902, 257.033600881696, 
    285.703909397125, 282.119815647602, 275.972167104483, 0, 
    1, 0), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gt"))))
```

Comment: Please share some of your data by pasting the output of `dput(lst)` into your question.

Comment: Please see above!

Answer (score 1):

You are close, try:

```r
lapply(lst, \(x) {x[,3] <- sample(x[,3]); x})
```